Baking Normal Map Problem
Why doesn't my baked result look like the object in highpoly? does anyone know about this problem?

Highpoly Object



Low Poly + Baked Result



When dealing with normal maps, precision and resolution matter.
For optimal results, maps should be baked on a 32 bit float image, with generous resolution (like 4096x4096), and stored as open EXR files with full 32 bit, zip loseless codec and non-color as color space, taking care that UV maps use nearly all UV space available.
Be aware that normal maps cannot take care of lack of roundness in the geometry: add and apply a subsurf modifier for this issue.


